# How to write an IF statement in JSON Formatting on a SharePoint List to get the user's profile image based upon a chosen field value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, person-or-group

I'm writing an IF statement in JSON formatting to get a particular image for a card view.

Basically, if the SharePoint field 'IndOrTeam' equals 'Team', then a group image stored in Site Assets is shown. This is working fine, however if 'IndOrTeam' does NOT equal 'Team' I want to show the user's profile picture, who is set in the 'AssignedTo' field. I know this can be accessed by the operator `'=getUserImage([$AssignedTo], 'L')'` but I can't get it to work in the IF statement.

If I remove the IF statement altogether, the user profile pic is shown as expected. The code is below. Does anyone know why it isn't showing the user profile image:

```
elmType": "img",
          "style": {
            "width": "150px",
            "height": "150px",
            "border-radius": "50%",
            "border": "1px solid"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "src": "=if([$IndOrTeam] == 'Team','https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/SiteAssets/groupusers.png','=getUserImage([$AssignedTo.email], 'L')'",
            "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralTertiaryAlt"
          },
          "defaultHoverField": "[$AssignedTo]"
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SharePoint JSON formatting expression like this:

```
"src": "=if([$IndOrTeam] == 'Team', 'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/SiteAssets/groupusers.png', getUserImage([$AssignedTo.email], 'l'))",
```

Where `IndOrTeam` and `AssignedTo` are internal name of your SharePoint list columns. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thanks. Updated the code. I'm sure I'd tried to re-write like that previously, but must have missed something or made a mistake. Now it works as expected! :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!